# Multi instance in Redirect URI with openid / AppAuth-Android

Tags: android, redirect, deep-linking, appauth

when I use this library:
https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android

have an issue when trying to use the deep link and open application. in this case, I have a multi-instance of my app with the same name and package name. I want to just one instance. (when I touch in one of the instances redirect happen but when touching the other one nothing happen)

everything works perfectly good and only I have this issue.
I saw these issues too:

https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/issues/329

https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/issues/481

https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/issues/491

and this is my code inside manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name=".util.deeplink.appAuth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
            tools:node="replace">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="test"
                    android:host="ops" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we found the solution. we have to just add

```
<activity android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
            tools:node="replace"/>
```

besides our custom class:

```
<activity
            android:name=".util.deeplink.appAuth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
```

into manifest file